# Laravel - [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

So I'm creating my first SPA in Laravel, along with vue. I decided to use Laravel mix instead of webpack and it seems to have broken for me, I now receive

`[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

Seems to happen when I add `<router-view></router-view>`.

I've tried the "solution" of adding `.default`, didn't work.

```
export default new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: require('./views/Home.vue').default
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            component: require('./views/About.vue').default
        }
    ]
});
```

app.js:

```
import './bootstrap';
import router from './routes';

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
});
```

bootstrap.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import axios from 'axios';


window.Vue = Vue;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

routes.js:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

export default new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: require('./views/Home.vue')
        }
    ]
});
```

HTML (welcome.blade.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>

            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
        <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please provide your `app.js` file

Comment: I've added my JS files. Thanks!

Comment: good, and where are you putting `<router-view></router-view>`?

Comment: That would be in my `welcome.blade.php` file in Laravel, just under my `<router-link to="/">Home</router-link>`. I have attached that code also.

Comment: did you try to put view-router inside `app.vue` and instantiate app component in blade template like `<app></app>`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim OP does not have an `app.vue`

Comment: Can you please provide your `Home.vue` component definition

Answer (score 0):

From bootstrap.js delete `import VueRouter from 'vue-router';` and `Vue.use(VueRouter);` and add Router plugin to Vue inside of **routes.js** file and edit it as below:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
export default new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: require('./views/Home.vue')
        }
    ]
});
```

**app.js** is correct. I have implemented and tested this everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to fix my own issue.

Add `.default` to `require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue')` Like so `require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default`

Answer (score 0):

Replace all webpack resolve aliases with relative paths

I stubmled across an issue where the the webpack [chunkhash] placeholder in the output.chunkFilename webpack option causes an issue

Modifying webpack optimization.splitChunks.chunks option

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const tailwind = require('tailwindcss');
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const pwa = require('sw-precache-webpack-plugin');

mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    ],
});

mix.version();

// ...

mix.js('resources/js/app/app.js', 'public/js/app.js');
```